# Fixed column-width table with text left-aligned in cells

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, columns

```
\section{Section Title} %label{8.4.47}
\subsection*{Some note on Section}
\begin{footnotesize}
\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}|p{4cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}}
Heading 1 & Heading 2 & Heading 3  & Heading 4 \\
\hline
Text 1  & Text 2 & A\textsuperscript {6/1} B\textsuperscript {5/1} C\textsuperscript {1/2}  D\textsuperscript {7/1} (E + F)\textsuperscript{8.4.46} (G + H)\textsuperscript{8.4.45} Some more text\textsuperscript{6.1.72} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{footnotesize}
```

In the above table `|p{3cm}` is making the columns justified. I get some unwanted space between the characters, is there a way to make it align to the left, if the text does not fit in a line either put a "-" and continue to next line or simply start from a new line.

Also can I post my code with Unicode characters?

Comment: You can post on this site in Unicode just fine: şéê?  If you want to know about Unicode in TeX, that's also possible; there have been a number of questions here about doing just that.  And in general, if you have a specific question about this site, you should ask it over at [meta](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You could use the `array` package and let it insert `\raggedright` commands. A comfortable way is to define a new column type:

```
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
```

Now just use `P` instead of `p` to get left justified p columns.

Instead of `\raggedright`, you could also use the enhanced command `\RaggedRight` of the `ragged2e` package, which allows hyphenation. Further `\arraybackslash`, which restores the behavior of \ (changed by `\raggedright`), is no longer needed.

So, my preferred way would be

```
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
```

I'm further inserting `\hspace{0pt}` because otherwise there could be hyphenation problems: TeX doesn't hyphenate the first word in a box. Inserting zero space works around that.

Comment: I am very new to Tex and still do not know how to implement your solution.

Comment: @Aku: just add my code lines to your preamble (either the 2 line at the beginning or the variant with 2 lines). Then change your tabular definition to use the capital P: `\begin{tabular}{P{2cm}|P{4cm}|P{3cm}|P{3cm}}`.

Comment: Is it possible to make this work with `tabularx` as well? If I do exactly the same in a `tabularx` the text simply stays left aligned. I need a `tabularx` because I want my table to have a flexible column, maintaining exactly 100% text width overall.

Comment: @bluenote10, `\raggedright` aligns *left*. For right-aligning, with tabularx, you can redefine the X column: `\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}` (notice this uses `\raggedleft`)

Answer (score 12):

The version 2.4f of `array` has introduced new types of columns: `w{...}{...}` and `W{...}{...}`. The first argument is `l`, `c` or `r` and the second is the width of the column. With `W`, you have a warning if the content of the cell is too wide.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|wl{2cm}|wr{3cm}|}
\hline
qsdf & poiu \\
\hline
pqsdg aer & pou azer \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: This is _the_ answer!

Comment: How can I impose text wrapping in such a column?

Comment: @kapple: Use standard column types `p`, `m`, `b` of the package `array`.