# line-breaking in longtable

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, longtable

I'm using the longtable environment with the field `p{0.5\textwidth}`. The text on that field is set with very odd spacing, because latex attempts to justify it both for the left and right column margins. I tried setting `\raggedright` for the entire document, but this has no effect on the text in the field. Can anyone suggest a quick fix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to apply this to all `p`-columns you could consider this:

```
\usepackage[raggedrightboxes]{ragged2e}
```

From the documentation:

> All \parboxes, minipages, \marginpars
>   and p-columns of tabulars and arrays
>   are automatically set using
>   \RaggedRight.

If you want to apply `\RaggedRight` only to a particular column, you can insert it into its format definition: `>{\RaggedRight}p{0.5\textwidth}`.

Comment: @Mayer See also [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7347/fixed-column-width-table-with-text-left-aligned-in-cells/7348#7348) for a more localised solution (also using `ragged2e`).

Comment: The only problem with using ragged2e is that it seems to be incompatible with the bidi package. In my specific project, however, I didn't need to use the bidi (I load it automatically for xelatex), so I dropped it and all is working well. Thanks!