# Controlling cell width and height simultaneously in a table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to create a multi-page table with all cells having the same height (as well as certain fixed widths) so that certain manual cut-and-paste operations are a lot easier.  One issue is that one column in particular is text-heavy and should line-break within the cell.  As I don't want it justified, I looked into alternatives such as [Fixed column-width table with text left-aligned in cells](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7347/fixed-column-width-table-with-text-left-aligned-in-cells/7348#7348).  This is doing exactly what I want for horizontal alignment.

For vertical alignment, I've looked at [How to specify a fixed height for all rows in a table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12761/how-to-specify-a-fixed-height-for-all-rows-in-a-table/12780#12780) and the `\vphantom` method detailed in the above link doesn't seem to be working.

Here's what I'm currently working with:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\hspace{0pt}\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\def\Z{\vphantom{\parbox[c]{1.7in}{\Huge Something Long}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{| c || P{0.5in} || P{0.5in} || P{5in} |}\hline

1.  \Z &&& Long long long long long long long long long
            long long long long long long long text  \\\hline
2.  \Z &&& More long long long long long long long long
            long long long long long long long text  \\\hline
\end{tabular}
```

When I compile, the cells do not have a uniform height, and none of them are as large as 1.7 inches vertically.  So this suggests that somehow the `\vphantom` method is failing.

Does anybody know of a relatively straightforward solution to this problem?

Comment: The problem here is that [`\parbox[<position>]{<width>}{<text>}`](http://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/latex/ltx-294.html) specifies the `<width>`, not the `<height>` of `<text>`. Herbert's suggestion to use `>{\rule{0pt}{<height>}}` for the first column puts a zero-width rule of height `<height>` in each row, effectively making them all the same height.

Comment: Werner: alright, that makes sense.  For some reason I thought the argument to `\parbox` was the height of the resulting `\vphantom`.  Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this example each cell has a height of 3cm:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{| >{\rule{0pt}{3cm}}c || P{0.5in} || P{0.5in} || P{3in} |}\hline

1. &&& Long long long long long long long long long
            long long long long long long long text  \\\hline
2. &&& More long long long long long long long long
            long long long long long long long text  \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```