# how to set absolute tabular cell/row height and width

Tags: tables, height

I am designing a tabular table (row/cell) containing 40 rows, 10 cells per row.  A requirement is that the rows be 7mm in height and cells 17mm in width.  The width I seem to have found.

I have not found a method (so far) to set an absolute/fixed row height.  Does such a mechanism exist, and if so, a pointer to the documentation would be most appreciated.

- rob

Comment: like [Controlling cell width and height simultaneously in a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24730/117534)?