# \flushleft with p{} option in tabular

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

If I have defined `tabular` alignment with the `p{}` option,

```
\begin{tabular}{p{.3\textwidth}p{.7\textwidth}}
...(contents)...
\end{tabular}
```

Is there a way to specify that I want it `\flushleft` without wrapping the contents of each cell in a `\parbox` or `minipage` environment? It might be trouble in the example above, but I have dozens of cells, so is not a very feasible solution (unless I program something with Emacs Lisp).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Load the **array** package and write

```
\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright}p{.3\textwidth}
                >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{.6\textwidth}}
```

It's necessary to use the `\arraybackslash` in the last column, otherwise `\\` would not end the table row. You can use `\newline` to end lines in the last column cells (and the regular `\\` in the other column cells).

By the way, a tabular specification like yours will give an overfull box, as you are not keeping into account the intercolumn spaces. If you want that the table extends all the way of the line width, say

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\raggedright}p{.3\textwidth-\tabcolsep}
                >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{.7\textwidth-\tabcolsep}@{}}
```

after loading the **calc** package. Or, without it

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}
                >{\raggedright}
                p{\dimexpr.3\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax}
                >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}
                p{\dimexpr.7\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax}@{}}
```

The two `@{}` avoid the insertion of the intercolumn space before and after the tabular.

Comment: I like to define something like `\def\myraggedright{\rightskip0mm plus10mm\relax}` and use that instead of `\raggedright` in the column definition. This way you have the text flushed left without the large space between words, but with hyphenation, so that the output looks much less ragged than with `\raggedright`.

Comment: @ElmarZander You can also use the `ragged2e` package and its `\RaggedRight` command that does something similar to yours.

Answer (score 10):

You could use a feature of the `array` package to insert a `\raggedright` command for flush left text, use `>{command}` before the column definition to insert one or several command(s):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{.3\textwidth}p{.7\textwidth}}
    \blindtext & \blindtext
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

You mentioned `\flushleft` - you could use it but it can insert undesired vertical space, such as

```
\begin{tabular}{>{\flushleft\arraybackslash}p{.3\textwidth}<{\endflushleft}p{.7\textwidth}}
```

If you need it often, consider defining a new column type using `array` features, as I did [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7347/fixed-column-width-table-with-text-left-aligned-in-cells/7348#7348):

```
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
```

Some people define further useful types, such as

```
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
```

etc. So your tabular definition becomes simpler:

```
\begin{tabular}{P{.7\textwidth}P{.3\textwidth}}
```

In narrow columns, it may be good to allow hyphenation. This can be done using `ragged2e`. `microtype` could improve even more. So I would use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{microtype}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{P{.7\textwidth}P{.3\textwidth}}
    \blindtext & \blindtext \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

With `ragged2e` commands `\arraybackslash` is not needed. As the first word in a box would not be hyphenated, I additionally inserted zero horizontal space.

Comment: `\arraybackslash` is necessary only in the last column.

Comment: Still works with it though... and I like the convenience of having a new column type!