# Table: Text is Streched (Fully-Justified) and Looks Ugly - Looking for Left Aligned (\raggedright)

Tags: tables, spacing

I have a table containing a few lines that don't extend all the way to the end. These lines being end up being stretched beyond presentability. I've tried several methods looked up here and none seem to work.
The only thing that does is putting it in Math mode, which is not what I want for the table I am working with.

The line

```
not(dep(adjective, dep)), (dep(adjective, nmod)
```

ends up looking like

```
not(dep(adjective,     dep)),     (dep(adjective,     nmod)
```

in order to fit the space in the Table

My MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[t]
\small
\caption{\small \label{table-4} \textit{Table}}
\begin{tabular}{|p{13.5cm}|}
\hline

not(dep(adjective, dep)), (dep(adjective, nmod) 
not(pos(parent(adjective), RB)), not(dep(children(adjective), nsubj)))   facet(States);

\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12703 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31508

Comment: I edited the title of your question. If i got it wrong then change it back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your table has two issues. The first, already mentioned in your posting, is that it would be better if the material were typeset ragged-right rather than fully justified. The second issue is that the `tabular` environment is quite a bit wider than the text block.

To remedy both problems, I suggest you use a `tabularx` environment, with width set to `\textwidth`, and that you use a modified form of the `X` column type that typesets its material ragged-right (aka flushleft) while still allowing hyphenation. See the code below for an implementation of these suggestions.

Separately, instead of engaging in visual formatting by typing `\caption{\small \label{table-4} \textit{Table}}`, consider loading the `caption` package and using suitable arguments for a `\captionsetup` instruction. Again, see the code below for a specific implementation of this recommendation.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,caption}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\captionsetup{size=small,textfont=it,skip=0.333\baselineskip}
\small
\caption{Table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|Y|}
\hline
not(dep(adjective, dep)), (dep(adjective, nmod) 
not(pos(parent(adjective), RB)), not(dep(children(adjective), nsubj))) facet(States);
\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, I can't compete with that :).

Answer (score 3):

Following the questions I mentioned in my comment, you can use this for example (`array` package and `\raggedright` command):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[t]
\small
\caption{\small \label{table-4} \textit{Table}}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{135mm}|}
\hline
not(dep(adjective, dep)), (dep(adjective, nmod) 
not(pos(parent(adjective), RB)), not(dep(children(adjective), nsubj)))   facet(States);\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]