# Table and \flushleft

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I'm trying to `\flushleft` the contents of a table, but wasn't successful so far. Several [sources](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31508/flushleft-with-p-option-in-tabular) state that one should use `\raggedright` to do this, but I found no complete example to see how this can be incorporated without getting errors.

This is my (reduced) code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace,amsmath,graphicx,float}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{boldline}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[left=3cm,top=3.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{caption}

\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}       % top strut
\newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[-1.1ex]{0pt}{0pt}} % bottom strut

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{flushleft}
\centering
\small
    \caption[Steps in a hypothetical monopolist test]{Steps in a hypothetical monopolist test.}
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{ p{3em} p{11em}  p{11em}  p{12em} }    
    \hlineB{3}
    \bf  &    
    \bf Step 1 & 
    \bf Step 2 & 
    \bf Step 3 \Tstrut\Bstrut \\ \hline
    PMD\tnote{*} & (1) & (1, 2) & (1, 2, 3) \Tstrut\Bstrut \\
    Q & Does monopolization of product 1 give pricing power? & Does a hypothetical monopolist of products 1 and 2 have pricing power? & Does a hypothetical monopolist of products 1, 2 and 3 have pricing power? \Tstrut\Bstrut \\ 
    A & No, because there are two perfect substitutes omitted from the proposed market. No ability to raise price of good 1. & No, because there is still a perfect substitute omitted from the proposed market (product 3) that constrains the ability of the hypothetical monopolist of goods 1 and 2 to raise their prices. & Yes, if products 4 and 5 are not good enough substitutes. If so, then the market definition of (1, 2, 3) is accepted. No, if either product 4 or 5 is a good enough substitute to constrain profitability of a price increase. In that case, continue the test. \Tstrut\Bstrut \\                     
    \hlineB{3}
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
    \item[*] Proposed market definition.
    \end{tablenotes}       
    \end{threeparttable}
\label{HMTStepByStep}
\end{flushleft}    
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

And output:
[image]

Here the original source which I wish to recreate as closely as possible:
[image]

I did some changes to the original source which I personally find more appealing to the eye, but my main goal is really to `\flushleft` and get rid of all the `Underfull \hbox` errors.

Can anyone please help to achieve this?

(Spacing is another topic which I will have to solve this later)

Comment: you have flush left and then on the next line undo its effects with `\centering`:   `\begin{flushleft}
\centering`

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle - I removed the `\centering` for testing purposes, but sadly the output remains the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Welcome:)** Replace this `{ p{3em} p{11em}  p{11em}  p{12em} }` with this `{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{3em}>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{11em}  p{11em}>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{12em}}`

With the package `\usepackage{array,ragged2e}`

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Saravanan! It did help to bind everything to the left, but somehow it also increased the spacing between the first two columns. See [here](https://s27.postimg.org/74q9kk7o3/image.jpg). The upper image shows the old code and the lower one the new one.

Comment: Reduce the {11em} to 9 or 8 em.. hope it helps

Comment: Ah, I was even increasing it - thank you, this did the trick.