# How to make a content in a table cell move to left, using "\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}cXccccc}"

Tags: tables, tabularx

I want to move content (in a circle picture below) to the left as shown in example 1.

[image]

Is it because i am using:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}cXccccc}
```

My full MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline, boldline}
\usepackage{seqsplit, caption} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{booktabs, ragged2e} % Use booktabs rules and get rid of vertical rules, ragged2e to ragged text
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{threeparttable} %to add footnote below table
\usepackage{tabulary}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xccccc}
    \toprule
    & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Paired Differences}} \\
     \cmidrule{3-5}
     & & \small {\textbf{Mean (\%)}}
     & \thead{\small {\textbf{Std. Deviation}}\\ \textbf{(\%)}}& \thead{\small {\textbf{Std. Error}} \\ \textbf{Mean (\%)}} \\
\midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Pair 1} & \textit{Aaaaaa example dataset} (AA) - \textit{Aaaaaa example dataset} (BB) 
    & 44.76 & 14.92 & 4.72  \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Example making content to left}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}cXccccc}
        \toprule
    & & \multicolumn{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{8em}}{\textbf{95\% Confidence Interval of the Difference}}  &  \multirow{4.5}{*}{\textbf{t}}
      & \multirow{4.5}{*}{\textbf {df}} 
      & \multirow{4.5}{*}{\makecell{\textbf{Sig.}\\ \textbf{(2-tailed)}}}  \\
     \cmidrule{3-4}  %\cmidrule(lr){3-4}
     & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Lower}} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Upper}} & & &\\
\midrule
    Pair 1 & \textit{Aaaaaa example dataset} (AA) - \textit{Aaaaaa Example Dataset} (B\textbf{}) & 34.09\% &  55.44\% & 9.49 & 9 & .000\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
        \caption{Example 2}
\end{table}
% \end{center}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xccccc}` in your second table. In comparison to your original code, I have moved <{...}` from before `c` to before `X` just as it is already placed in the first table.

Comment: @leandriis. Thanks. Brillant! Can close this question. I think i still need time to figure out the meaning of `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xccccc}`

Comment: `c>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xccccc`: first column centered, second column: variable width, `X` type, left aligned instead of justified; third to  last column: centered. Hope, this short explanation helps.

Comment: This question should be helpful: [Table and \flushleft](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/346237)