# Generated Table Format Issue

Tags: tables, formatting, pdf, nicematrix

I wrote a simple code to generate a simple table.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,english]{report}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table} 
\begin{NiceTabular}{| p{0.2\linewidth} | p{0.4\linewidth} | p{0.4\linewidth} |} % Don't Modify
\hline 
\textbf{\small{BLAA}}       
& \textbf{\small{BLABLABLABL}}      
& \textbf{\small{BLABLABLABLAB / BLAA BLAAAA}}                                               
\\ \hline 
JIRA Ticket gggggggg-190 
& Second Column
& Third Column  
\\ \hline 
\end{NiceTabular} % Don't Modify
\end{table} % Don't Modify

\end{document}
```

The output pdf have a format issue at which there are many spaces between "JIRA" and "Ticket"

The output pdf:

[image]

Any help ?

Comment: unrelated but size commands do not take an argument so `\small{BLABLABLABL}`  should be `\small BLABLABLABL` by default `p` columns are justified you can set them ragged right with `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{..}`

Comment: also `\begin{NiceTabular}{| p{0.2\linewidth} | p{0.4\linewidth} | p{0.4\linewidth} |} % Don't Modify`  this makes a table that is too wide as the you have 1\linewidth for the total text width on each column but you have `\tabcolsep` padding around each column and four | so you are 6\tabcolsep+4\arrayrulewidth too wide for the page.

Comment: The table option `p` makes justified text, you could change it to left align. You can define `\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}` (see [\flushleft with p{} option in tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31508/flushleft-with-p-option-in-tabular?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

Comment: Put a \\ just after Ticket and you are done.

Comment: Try `\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
{
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr#1-2\tabcolsep-4\arrayrulewidth/3}}
\noindent\begin{NiceTabular}{ L{0.3\linewidth}  L{0.35\linewidth}  L{0.35\linewidth} }[hvlines]
\RowStyle{\small\bfseries}
BLA     &   BLABLABLABL     & BLABLABLABLAB / BLAA BLAAAA   \\
JIRA Ticket gggggggg-190
        &   Second Column   & Third Column                  \\
    \end{NiceTabular}
}
\end{document}
`