# Newline linespacing problems within a table cell

Tags: tables, line-breaking, longtable, tabularx

I have problems with the linespace inside a `longtable` environment when forcing a linebreak. Following code should illustrate the problem.

```
\documentclass[11pt,paper=a4,11pt,parskip=half,draft]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\definecolor{darkblue}{HTML}{212650}
\definecolor{grey}{HTML}{666666}

\newcommand{\itemdate}[1]{{\sffamily #1}}
\newcommand{\itemhead}[1]{{\sffamily\textcolor{darkblue}{\bfseries #1}}}
\newcommand{\itemplace}[1]{{\sffamily\itshape\footnotesize #1}}
% don't know why this cannot be local scope only ???!!!!
\newcommand{\iteminfo}[1]{\scriptsize #1}

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7348/46403
% ragged2e packages provides text hyphenation in columns
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\hspace{0pt}\arraybackslash}p{#1}}   % left with dimension
\newcolumntype{J}[1]{>{\justifying\hspace{0pt}\arraybackslash}p{#1}}    % justify with dimension

\newcommand{\colwidth}[1]{%
    \dimexpr #1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep%
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}[!htbp]{|@{}L{\colwidth{0.2}}|L{\colwidth{0.8}}@{}|}

    \hline
    \itemdate{Itemdate 1} &
    \itemhead{Itemhead 1} \newline
    \itemplace{Itemplace 1} \vspace{3pt}\newline
    \iteminfo{\textbf{Iteminfo 1.1}: \blindtext[1]}
    \vspace{3pt}\newline%
    \iteminfo{\textbf{Iteminfo 1.2}: \blindtext[1]} \\

    \hline
    \itemdate{Itemdate 2} &
    \itemhead{Itemhead 2} \newline
    \itemplace{Itemplace 2} \\

    \hline
    \itemdate{Itemdate 3} &
    \itemhead{Itemhead 3} \newline
    \itemplace{Itemplace 3} \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

<sub>Also available at https://www.overleaf.com/2029617ptbycv#/5121602/</sub>

I hope this demonstrates the problem well enough.

If you look at the spacing between *Itemhead 1* and *Itemplace 1*, this is the linespacing I would like to have.

The spacing between Itemhead 2 and Itemplace 2 as well as Itemhead 3 and Itemplace 3 is in my opinion too wide for a single newline. It should be singlespaced.

Right now I have no idea what forces latex to use a wider linespread between the Itemhead and Itemplace lines in row 2 and 3. Is must have something to do with the text following the Itemplace line. Because if I call `\iteminfo` after the `\itemplace` command, it shows that strange behaviour.

I am using MacTex 2014 on OSX 10.10.1.

This is how it looks like on OSX 10.10.1 Preview-App
[image: This is how it looks like on OSX 10.10.1 Preview-App]

Comment: This is really strange. I'm going to update all my packages and attach a image illustrating the effect. Thank's for your other hints.

Comment: After updating all packages the same effect is still there.

Comment: The same happens in Adobe Acrobat Pro on OSX 10.10.1 and Acrobat Reader XI on Windows 7 and also on the webeditor link posted above. @Mico May I ask which pdf reader you are using?

Comment: I can confirm that the spacing is as shown above, for me, on my Ubuntu TeXLive system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should always include end of paragraph (*not* `\newline`) if you have size changes. An entire paragraph is set with the baselinespacing in force at the end of the paragraph, so you were getting inconsistent settings.

```
\documentclass[11pt,paper=a4,11pt,parskip=half,draft]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\definecolor{darkblue}{HTML}{212650}
\definecolor{grey}{HTML}{666666}

\newcommand{\itemdate}[1]{{\sffamily #1}}
\newcommand{\itemhead}[1]{{\sffamily\textcolor{darkblue}{\bfseries #1}}\par}
\newcommand{\itemplace}[1]{{\sffamily\itshape\footnotesize #1\par}}
% don't know why this cannot be local scope only ???!!!!
\newcommand{\iteminfo}[1]{{\scriptsize #1\par}}

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7348/46403
% ragged2e packages provides text hyphenation in columns
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\hspace{0pt}\arraybackslash}p{#1}}   % left with dimension
\newcolumntype{J}[1]{>{\justifying\hspace{0pt}\arraybackslash}p{#1}}    % justify with dimension

\newcommand{\colwidth}[1]{%
    \dimexpr #1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep%
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}[!htbp]{|@{}L{\colwidth{0.2}}|L{\colwidth{0.8}}@{}|}

    \hline
    \itemdate{Itemdate 1} &
    \itemhead{Itemhead 1}
    \itemplace{Itemplace 1}
    \iteminfo{\textbf{Iteminfo 1.1}: \blindtext[1]}
    \iteminfo{\textbf{Iteminfo 1.2}: \blindtext[1]} \\

    \hline
    \itemdate{Itemdate 2} &
    \itemhead{Itemhead 2}
    \itemplace{Itemplace 2} \\

    \hline
    \itemdate{Itemdate 3} &
    \itemhead{Itemhead 3}
    \itemplace{Itemplace 3} \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd omit the `[!htbp]` location specifier...

Comment: Thank you for the solution! This makes it clear to me what was going wrong!

Comment: @david-carlisle What I've read now is that \par adjusts \baselineskip of that paragraph. In the example above using \par adds a last blank line after the last sentence which i want to avoid. My question would be if there exists another latex command which also sets the correct baselineskip value, like par, but does not start a newline (to avoid the blank line at every last paragraph ...)? I've tried to work with \par\vspace{-\baselineskip}, but this doesn't remove the last blank line.

Answer (score 4):

The reason you're getting different spacing results is because (a) you're using `\newline` instead of `\par` to insert line breaks and (b) different font sizes are used for items of type Itemhead (`\normalsize`), Itemplace (`\footnotesize`), and Iteminfo (`\scriptsize`).

The interline space that is used in a (logical) paragraph depends on the fontsize that's in effect at the *end* of the current paragraph. Importantly, `\newline` inserts a line break but it does *not* initiate a new paragraph. Thus, in the Itemhead1/Itemplace1/Iteminfo1 group, the spacing between Itemhead1 and Itemplace1 is what's appropriate for `\scriptsize` material (and thus quite tight) as `\scriptsize` is in effect at the end of the "paragraph". This effect is obscured because you have `\vspace{3pt}` instructions ahead of each Iteminfo element.

Conversely, in the case of Itemhead2/Itemplace2 and Itemhead3/Itemplace 3, the paragraph's final font size is `\footnotesize`, and you thus get (slightly) wider spacing than for the first group.

If you absolutely, positively must get the very tight spacing that's appropriate for `\scriptsize` material, you can get this result by inserting the instruction `\scriptsize` immediately after `\itemplace{Itemplace 2}`. However, I think you're better off replacing all `\newline` instructions with `\par` and getting rid of the `\vspace{3pt` instructions.

Comment: Mico, thank you for your explanation. I accepted David answer because he was faster an I can only accept one ... Thanks for all!