# Table questions on multiply row caption

Tags: tables

[image: What I want....]

and what I am currently at.....

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper, top=1in, bottom=1in, left=0.75in, right=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow,array,varwidth,spreadtab,}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,caption}

\begin{document}

    \captionsetup{labelformat=empty}
     \centering \caption{DISCOUNTED \\ FUTURE NET INCOME -M\$ \\COMPOUNDED MONTHLY}

     \begin{tabular}{cr}
       \toprule
    0.00 = & 0 \\
    0.00 = &  0\\
    0.00 = &  0\\
    0.00 = &  0\\
    0.00 = &  0\\

      \multicolumn{2}{l}{%
      \footnotesize
      %
    }
    \end{tabular}

    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the question?  Additionally, a MWE starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`   And then just the minimum information to show the problem or question.

Comment: What do the dashes next to the numbers in the left-hand column mean? Are they supposed to be "minus" signs? If something else: What? Please advise.

Comment: It's not minus signs, it is "=" sign, poor PDF generator quality.

Comment: I just edited to show the case better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED:  Add the requested horizontal rule.

EDITED:  Added the blank line to get a new paragraph.

EDITED:  Column justification.

Here is an edit that compiles.  However, what is your question?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper, top=1in, bottom=1in, left=0.75in, right=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow,array,varwidth,spreadtab,}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,caption}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedLeft\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\begin{document}
    \captionsetup{labelformat=empty}
    \begin{table}
     \centering 
\caption{DISCOUNTED \\ FUTURE NET INCOME -M\$ \\COMPOUNDED MONTHLY}
\vspace{-1em}\rule{0.3\textwidth}{1.25pt}

     \begin{tabular}{cr}
    0.00 = & 0 \\
    0.00 = &  0\\
    0.00 = &  0\\
    0.00 = &  0\\
    0.00 = &  0\\

      \multicolumn{2}{l}{%
      \footnotesize
      %
    }

    \end{tabular}

    \end{table}

 Here is an alternative using \textit{ragged2e} and \textit{array}.   

    \begin{table}
     \centering 
\caption{DISCOUNTED \\ FUTURE NET INCOME -M\$ \\COMPOUNDED MONTHLY}
\vspace{-1em}\rule{0.3\textwidth}{1.25pt}


     \begin{tabular}{L{.12\textwidth}R{.12\textwidth}}% From http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7347/fixed-column-width-table-with-text-left-aligned-in-cells
    0.00 = & 0 \\
    0.00 = &  0\\
    0.00 = &  0\\
    0.00 = &  0\\
    0.00 = &  0\\

      \multicolumn{2}{l}{%
      \footnotesize
      %
    }
    \end{tabular}

    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I want to extend the /toprule to match the Fig 1 (Top figure )style.

Comment: Wow, how could you just simply did that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is that possible to make left value column flushleft and right column flushright with \hfill command? @R.Schumacher

Comment: @ChengZhang Note: Edited for column justification.   We prefer that when a question has been answered you accept the answer.  Then for another question,  you compose a new MWE illustrating the problem and ask the new question.   1) As soon as a question is accepted most of the active members of the TEX.SE will not reopen and look at the question again.  2) A  new question appears at the top of the board, however comments do not elevate the question, resulting in fewer resources for getting an answer.   And welcome to TEX.SE

Comment: OK, thanks for the advice to rookies. Will keep in mind.