# Centering text and symbols in tables with fixed column width

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, columns

I tried building a table with fixed column width and centered text/symbols. I used the following script.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |p{.1cm}|p{.1cm}|p{.1cm}| } 
  \hline $\bigcirc$ & A & A \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

I also tried using \centering and \hspace{...} to adjust the position of the text, but it doesn't work. How do I center the text/symbols within a column of some chosen width?

Comment: `\centering` does work. Package `array` would also allow to add it to the column declaration. So please show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) of what you've tried without success. BTW: 0.1cm is 1mm and therefore,depending on the font size, may be too low. Usually it is better to use a font size depending length, like `1em` or `1ex`.

Comment: See also: [How to create fixed width table columns with text raggedright/centered/raggedleft?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12703/277964), and for small columns i. e. [Fixed column-width table with text left-aligned in cells](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7347/277964) ([Pantigny's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/557749/277964) IMHO explains, what you are searching for).

Comment: Is your comment helping me solve the problem, egreg?

Comment: @samario28 - Egreg's question is quite serious: What are you trying to achieve by setting up columns whose *usable* width is 1 mm? If you were *not* being serious when you specified `p{.1cm}`, then please edit your posting to provide something that's more realistic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need line breaks within your cells, you could use either a `w` column (which will suppress the overfull box warning from your content being too wide for your .1cm column width) or use `W` column (and make sure that your columns are wide enough for your content):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |w{c}{.1cm}|w{c}{.1cm}|w{c}{.1cm}| } 
  \hline $\bigcirc$ & A & A \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}



\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |W{c}{.4cm}|W{c}{.4cm}|W{c}{.4cm}| } 
  \hline $\bigcirc$ & A & A \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer!
The first option seems to be working perfectly for my case!

Comment: @samario28 You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to employ the `p` ("paragraph") column type -- say, because you need automatic line-breaking within cells -- you should (a) load the `array` package in the preamble and (b) use the following code

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | *{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}|}  } 
  \hline 
  $\bigcirc$ & A & A \\ 
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

to generate a `tabular` environment with three [3] columns with *centered* contents. If your document needs the centered variant of the `p` column type repeatedly, it's a good idea to define a bespoke new column type, as is done in the following example.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{array} % for '\newcolumntype' and '\arraybackslash' macros
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ | *{3}{P{1cm}|}  }
        \hline
        $\bigcirc$ & A & AAA AAAA AAA \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This crams the text into 1mm columns.  Note that the width of a column from | to | is the width of the largest entry plus `2\tabcolsep`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}% you probably want to remove this
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|} \hline 
  \makebox[.1cm]{$\bigcirc$} & \makebox[.1cm]{A} & \makebox[.1cm]{A} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]